# How can I decode thrice bytes encoded string?

Tags: python, utf-8, decoding

I've been working with a pandas dataframe, where one column was bytes encoded. I decoded it once with .decode('utf-8'), and it worked for the major part of the data, but there were some strings, that occured to be encoded more than once. For example: b'b'b\'[{"charcName":"\\\\u0420\\\\u0438\\\\u0441\\\\u0443\\\\u043d\\\\u043e\\\\u043a","charcValues":["\\\\u043c\\\\u0438\\\\u043b\\\\u0438\\\\u0442\\\\u0430\\\\u0440\\\\u0438 \\\\u043a\\\\u0430\\\\u043c\\\\u0443\\\\u0444\\\\u043b\\\\u044f\\\\u0436"]}]\'''

I tried to decode it consequently (and encode as well, in order to prevent an error 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'), but it doesn't seem to work. How can I decode such strings completely? In what order utf-8 and unicode_escape decoding should be applied?

Comment: You are complaining that the original data provider mangled the encoding and did not disclose to you the details of such processing. Complain to them, learn how the bits were transformed, and either fix the problem for them, or demand that they fix it properly. Random encoding transforms is not, in general, something that computer algorithms can “fix”. It’s a lossy function. Humans need to publish and conform to the specs.

Answer (score 1):

The original string wasn't valid so I stripped one bad layer of bytes-decoration and focused on decoding the remainder.  It won't work on the other entries since I manually stripped the bad part of the invalid string.  Tell the hacks upstream to fix it.

```py
import ast
import json

s = b'b\'[{"charcName": "\\\\u0420\\\\u0438\\\\u0441\\\\u0443\\\\u043d\\\\u043e\\\\u043a", "charcValues": ["\\\\u043c\\\\u0438\\\\u043b\\\\u0438\\\\u0442\\\\u0430\\\\u0440\\\\u0438 \\\\u043a\\\\u0430\\\\u043c\\\\u0443\\\\u0444\\\\u043b\\\\u044f\\\\u0436"]}]\''
s = ast.literal_eval(s.decode())
s = ast.literal_eval(s.decode())

print('# Original object:')
print(s)
print('\n# Properly encoded in JSON (tell the hacks of the original data how to do it):')
print(json.dumps(s))
print('\n# Or this, but make sure to write this to a UTF-8-encoded database or file.')
print(json.dumps(s, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Output:

```
# Original object:
[{'charcName': 'Рисунок', 'charcValues': ['милитари камуфляж']}]

# Properly encoded in JSON (tell the hacks of the original data how to do it):
[{"charcName": "\u0420\u0438\u0441\u0443\u043d\u043e\u043a", "charcValues": ["\u043c\u0438\u043b\u0438\u0442\u0430\u0440\u0438 \u043a\u0430\u043c\u0443\u0444\u043b\u044f\u0436"]}]

# Or this, but make sure to write this to a UTF-8-encoded database or file.
[{"charcName": "Рисунок", "charcValues": ["милитари камуфляж"]}]
```